# Creating 3D Models for a Game using Blender and Bloom Effect in Graphics

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, blender

I am creating a game that requires heavy use of 3D Models. I started  using Blender for creating models. Here are some models which I came across while developing a model

1. I need to create a model of a Cube with Horizontal Grooves/Depressions and impart glow to those Grooves. I went through a blender tutorial which described how to impart glow to certain objects but I don't how to create a Cube with Grooves/Depressions.
2. Second Question is related more to the field of Graphics. What is Bloom effect ? Is it related to lighting models in any way? How do I impart it using Opengl and C++ ?

Comment: This looks like a good question for gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only try to help you with your second question, since I'm not experienced with blender. A Bloom effect is a graphical effect to visualize strong light sources. It is often implemented as a shader. The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_%28shader_effect%29) is actually quite interesting.

You should be able to find tons of tutorials for both OpenGL and DirectX respective their shader languages. A quick search provided these, which look promising:

- http://prideout.net/archive/bloom/
- http://doenemeier.de/2011/03-opengl-bloom-shader.html